# Deserialize json fails with IConfigurationSection

Tags: c#, json

I some json which I wantto deserialize.
The JSON looks like (code snippet):

```
{
   "Akka": {
       "log-config-on-start": "true"
   }
}
```

When I want to deserialize this with: 
`Configuration.GetSection("Akka").Get<AkkaConfig>();`

```
public class AkkaConfig
{
   [JsonProperty("log-config-on-start")]
   public string logconfigonstart { get; set; }
}
```

It fails because of the hyphens.
With newtonsoft the deserialization goes fine.

Comment: `GetSection()` doesn't deserialize the settings. That happened when the configuration object was built. All settings, from all providers were loaded and stored as key/value pairs. `Get` tries to map/bind those settings to the object you passed. JSON.NET isn't used at all in this step.  The easy solution is to *not* use dashes. The json settings file is meant to serve your application, not the other way round

Comment: I understand. Unfortunately I need the Json in dashes for the config of the Akka.net system. It accepts only the log-config-on-start instead of one without dashes.
I'm now using a work-around like:
'var config = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { akka = Configuration.GetSection("Akka").Get<AkkaConfig>()});'

Comment: The workaround doesn't load an object, it recreates the JSON string contained in the `Akka` section. You could get that with [GetSection("Akka").Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfigurationsection.value?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfigurationSection_Value)